# Calculating average rating on a post

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following entity:

```
post_id | post_title | post_body
-------------------------------------
1       | First post | Hello, world!
```

and would like to register ratings on the post, like so:

```
rating_id | rating_user_id | rating_post_id | rating_rating
1         | 23             | 1              | 3.5
```

My main concern/question is, how I should retrieve the average rating for a post. I know I can do this by using an SQL query like so:

```
SELECT AVG(rating_rating) FROM post_ratings WHERE rating_post_id = 2;
```

but I would have to call this query everytime I'd do `$post->getAverageRating()` - is this a big performance issue? (keeping in mind that there could be thousands of ratings per post)

An alternative would be to store the average rating in a new column in the `posts` table and have a cron job calculate the average or something?

What is the best way of going about this?

Comment: It really depends on the details of the use case.. database calls are expensive, so you want to try and minimize it. One approach is keeping an application cache which goes to the database every X minutes and loads new data (or all data from scratch) and calculates in memory, or loads the already calculated averages, but yet, you do it once every X minutes and not on every request for a post.

Comment: i worked on a review site, and we had a cron running 4 times a day which did what you suggested, the only difference the final rating was calculated in php

Comment: No. It isn't. As and when it becomes a big performance issue one of two things will occur. Either you will be rich enough to pay for someone to fix your performance issue, or you will be too rich to care.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue to run it every time, unless it's a massive site with high load and access. If that's the case, just run a cron job once an hour or once every 6 hours and create/update a cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue of efficiency

If and which these ratings will stack to a large amount, it would be preferable to save the calculated average
I would add 2 columns to the posts table, average_rating, total_ratings

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD COLUMN average_rating DECIMAL (9,2);
ALTER TABLE posts ADD COLUMN total_ratings UNSIGNED (9) DEFAULT 0;
```

And populate them whenever a new rating is added, so you won't need a cron job
Notice the order of the queries to calculate the average

The MySQL + PHP code should be something like:

```
    $query = "UPDATE posts SET total_ratings  = total_ratings + " . $rating_rating . " WHERE post_id = " . $post_id;
    $db->query($query);
    $query = "UPDATE posts SET average_rating = average_rating * (total_ratings -1 / total_ratings) + " . $rating_rating ." / total_ratings WHERE post_id = " . $post_id;
$db->query($query);
```

This way you can update the posts table immediately without any cron job

Answer (score 1):

As for comparing performance- It depends on

1. How static the ratings are.If you expect new ratings for existing posts, I would go with calculating them on the fly anyway.
2. How many posts you would need the ratings for as opposed to overall posts. If you have millions of posts and need the average rating only for a few thousands, it makes sense to do them separately also.

Answer (score 1):

Database calls are expensive especially when you have to average every time.

You have the following options that are more optimal compared to your current solution.

1. Have a column that calculates and stores the average rating of a post when the rating has been made like mentioned by the @Guy L
2. Implementing a Cache with TTL(Time To Live)

example:

```
public function getAverageRating() {
     $post_id = 'post' . $this->id;
     if(Cache::has($post_id))
         return Cache::get($post_id);
     $rating = //fetch rating from DB
     Cache::set($post_id, $rating, 120); //ratings will be in the cahce for 120secs
     return $rating
}
```

Hope it helps.